# What is this 'rational-developer-for-i' tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Since yesterday, [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2265151/mike) has been retagging [rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational) to [rational-developer-for-i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational-developer-for-i) tag.

- [Rational developer for power and ILE C compilers - Is ILE-C still supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2379861/6850771)
- [Setup/change RDP's default Output Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9991755/6850771)
- [AS/400 Wont compile Printer File under RDP 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11025138/6850771)
- [What are the utilities in AS/400](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11459578/6850771)
- [Multiple SYSLIB in a property group or multiple property groups in a COBOL program in Rational Developer for System Z](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24426917/6850771)
- [How do I configure RDi to work with Aldon LM i](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42715269/6850771)

This raises a few concerns:

- What's with the tag name, anyway? It looks like a tag that should be longer, but was cut off by the character limit.
- Why are people approving this edit? The tag is unclear and incomplete.
- It seems like he created this tag, because the first question that uses it was edited by him yesterday, but he doesn't have enough reputation.
- What is the [rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational) tag itself about? The guidance usage says:

  > "A rational is a number that can be expressed as the ratio of two integers. Rational can also refer to IBM's Rational family of products."

My best guess is that [rational-developer-for-i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational-developer-for-i) is supposed to be [rational-developer-for-ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational-developer-for-ibm), which would actually be helpful - the [rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational) tag seems unclear. What's going  on here, and what should we do about it?

#### Edits

The user proposed a [tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15508564) and [wiki excerpt edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15508565). Both were rejected.

<s>The tag was created yesterday. Proved by looking in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42764718/revisions) of the tag wiki.</s>

[Rational Developer for I](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/dev-ibm-i) is a real thing - but is it relevant to the questions tagged with it?

Comment: Kinda amusing that it's the actual proper name for the product and thus a valid tag *and* also looks like someone hit the 25-character limit and just stopped typing "IBM".

Comment: As to the questions, there probably needs to now be a ...for-z tag as well, and perhaps some further ones. Not enough adds to get me a badge, but probably more than just the one.

Comment: @ayhan the link seems to be dead now.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yep. Looks like IBM [renamed the venerable AS/400 to "System i"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_i) - so not only is the tag valid, it's probably a good deal more useful than the ambiguous "rational" tag.

Give the editor a cookie & teach them how to write useful tag wikis.

Comment: It may not be a good replacement for "rational" as a whole.  Rational was a company that IBM bought forever ago with several software suites.  RationalDeveloperForI seems to be an IDE.  But questions about things like RationalRose (their UML modeling kit) probably don't fit.  Rational itself probably should be busted into several tags, but I don't know enough about the various pieces of software under than name to say how many.

Comment: How did the user create the tag, though?

Comment: @MDXF It seems to have been initially created by [an 11k rep user](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24426917/revisions).

Comment: @TylerH yes, I've posted some more detail.

Comment: Yes, Shog9, and you were even close about my having to drop the IBM from the original suggestion, coincidentally.

Comment: Although the i includes the "venerable AS/400", it has some spanking Power-chip machines. The 9 (latest) will at some point have some brand-new type of memory. The operating system has a DBMS *integrated* (IBM's DB/2 for i).

Comment: Heh, gotta confess I'm not at all familiar with IBM's offerings these days; grew up near Rochester, so AS/400 is burned into my vocabulary.

Comment: The rename happened quite a while back.  "Rational Developer for I" is a commercial Eclipse-with-i-tooling and is intended to replace the native tools (that as a concept is doomed to fail because IBM cannot replicate the "run the tools on the machine itself including the debugger over telnet" experience with a massive Eclipse offering)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Do not underestimates IBM's ability to replicate a green screen.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I worked with it a while back.  You must have close to full network access between your Windows machine running RDi and the AS/400. That is a bit more than just a telnet connection.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Telnet uses TCP, and the AS/400 (now i-series) typically uses TN3270 (now with [encryption](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684860)) (or [FTP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaiq/rzaiqjoblog.htm) even); did you mean over a serial controller (sorry, "ASCII Workstation Controller")?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not old enough to have seen anything but the Client Services emulator (with siblings) but I was told that they kept a real terminal physically near the machine for system maintenance.  Regardless, the point I was trying to make was that the new tooling wasn't adapted because it wasn't as useful as the original tooling running on the machine itself for RPG/COBOL programmers, and there was not enough for Java programmers to outweigh just using any IDE with jt400.jar.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen [COBOL ON COGS](http://www.coboloncogs.org/INDEX.HTM).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch A while back.   We used Java to interface COBOL (OPM and ILE) to the real world.  Rather hard to do web services in COBOL so that's what I did.  Now I do other stuff :)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Same. And I have used `jt400`, usually to call a stored procedure (no idea what that was written in though).

Comment: Stored program calls are tedious through jdbc so straigh ProgramCalls. Slightly easier to manage error situations gracefully.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "the AS/400 (now i-series) typically uses TN3270" => it generally speaking uses TN5250 not TN3270. (IBM i has some 3270 support, which I've never looked into or used, so maybe it has some support for TN3270 as well, but just about everybody uses 5250 rather than 3270, and hence uses TN5250 not TN3270.)

Comment: @SimonKissane I'm not an expert on IBM terminal series; I believe TN3270 is still supported - and it's the protocol emulator I remember using. But they're almost certainly compatible terminals because IBM doesn't like to break compatibility.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch IBM has two main series of EBCDIC block mode terminals – 3270 and 5250. They are incompatible with each other. Midrange systems (IBM i, i5, AS/400, System/38, System/36, System/34) use 5250. 370/390/Z mainframes use 3270. Each terminal type has its own TELNET extension – TN3270 for 3270, TN5250 for 5250. If you were talking to an IBM i or AS/400, with very high likelihood, you were using 5250 over TN5250, not 3270 over TN3270.

Answer (score 43):

I created the tag, so that mystery is solved.

The user had been tagging with the existing [rational] tag, which itself is highly confusing. I pinged him on his oldest question:

> Hi Mike, can you pause with adding the rational tag questions. The tag
> is entirely unclear and is going to be very confusing rather than
> clarifying. – Bill Woodger Mar 10 at 16:56
>
> @Bill Woodger, no problem, I agree that the tag needs improving.
> Ideally I would like a new tag as well: A tag called RDi or
> ibm-rational-developer-for-i would be good as rational is more of a
> product family rather than a specific product. How can I request a new
> tag? – mike 2 days ago
>
> I've made a tag rational-developer-for-i. I
> had to drop the IBM because it made it too long. There is a
> rational-clearcase tag as well. – Bill Woodger 2 days ago

"Rational Developer" is an Eclipse-based IDE which communicates with a target system, either a z (Mainframe) or an i (Midrange). Although some questions about Rational Developer would be system-agnostic, the distinction-by-tag can be a useful clarification, and very useful for searching.

I know the tag is long, but it will work well for searching. Other Rational tags may appear as needed.

The original Rational tag certainly needs some work. I don't think it is useful at all, but there were 309 questions using it (in various ways) when I looked.

I was going to ask here when I could find a moment.

I will find time to put some description into the tag if no-one beats me to it.

Comment: Too bad I can't accept two answers...

Comment: You shouldn't re-tag questions to incomplete tags that lack a complete tag wiki. The tag wiki should contain a brief summary of what the tag is about (which shouldn't be a copy/paste from wikipedia etc) but also about how it should be used. Which kinds of questions should use this tag and should the tag get used together with the [rational] tag or not? If you are uncertain about how to write this, it might be a good idea to drop a draft here on meta and ask for feedback.

Comment: We could perhaps rename the tag to [tag:rational-developer-ibm] and leave out the 'for' bit... that would still be clear IMO and wouldn't leave you wondering what 'i' meant.

Comment: @Lundin while adding a tag wiki is useful, it seems that me that it isn't *necessary* for a tag as self-documenting as this one. Googling "rational developer for i" tells you what it is as the first result; the basic subject matter of the tag isn't ambiguous. I certainly don't think we should be telling off users for creating a clearly meaningful tag and attaching it to relevant questions just because they didn't provide a wiki. What's more, this user *did* provide a wiki and excerpt, which, while imperfect, were better than nothing. You're making the perfect the enemy of the good, here.

Comment: @Lundin also, note that it's (to the best of my knowledge) impossible through the UI to create a tag wiki or excerpt without first tagging some questions with the tag, so the instruction *"You shouldn't re-tag questions to incomplete tags that lack a complete tag wiki"* doesn't permit creation of new tags at all.

Comment: @TylerH an irony here is that the Bill already attempted to implement a perfectly good solution to the problem of people *"wondering what the 'i' meant"*, which was to [provide an excerpt that made clear that *Rational Developer for i* is a product name](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15508565)... but his excerpt was rejected on the grounds that the tag name was unambiguous and that therefore an excerpt that merely describes what the tag "is" shouldn't exist. Your (and others') reaction to the name suggests that those reviewers' reasoning (and the canned reason) are misguided.

Comment: @MarkAmery Oh, I gathered from the discussion above that the tag ending was being shortened from 'ibm' to 'i'. I didn't realize that it was supposed to be RDi-for-IBM

Comment: @MarkAmery Everyone who has posted here says that the [rational] tag is ambiguous and that it might mean multiple different things. That alone calls for for a tag usage description in the tag wiki. Possibly the [rational] tag should get burninated and split into several. It is fairly obvious that some manner of quality improvement is needed and that's what Bill Woodger was aiming for. All well and good, just follow the tag wiki policies established by the community. For example [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one).

Comment: @MarkAmery As for creating tags, that's not really related to editing existing questions and changing the tags. What you should do when creating one, is to write down a reasonable tag wiki and not just dump a link to an external site. This specific tag might be useful and called for, but there are very sound reasons why the community is restrictive with allowing new tags. Namely that the site is filled to the brim with nonsense tags and removing bad tags from the site takes a whole lot of effort.

Answer (score -4):

In my AS/400 world, "i" is synonymous with "IBMi" and "AS/400", although that system (from my understanding) is really just an update to the "AS/400" model everyone uses.