# Why do new tags not require usage guidance?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Meta spends a lot of time talking about tags, often about if a tag belongs on the site, and often these tags have no usage guidance. Tags seem like something that should only be added if there will be a lot of questions on it and at least a few people following that tag. It seems there are more tags created that shouldn't be, than tags that should exist but don't. I think we can afford to ask a bit more of people creating tags.

Should we require usage guidance when adding a new tag?

Comment: @yellowantphil honestly I don't even have that rep, so I'm not familiar on the current process. I just thought I'd start a discussion to better understand it.

Comment: Meta always likes to talk a lot about things that are out of their control.  I'm personally completely comfortable with it, but I grew up with it in my home country.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=en3J8JxxdVg) comes from back then.  Likely to be mystifying, skip to 5:00 to get the gist.

Answer (score 23):

The short answer here is that [implementing it was too complicated / difficult](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129624/promote-tag-wiki-creation-for-new-tags/131917#131917).

...Actually, that's the long answer too, but click through anyway if you're interested in my thoughts on the idea.

Comment: Interesting. It may be correct that the tag wiki isn't all that useful usually (except for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345415/what-is-this-rational-developer-for-i-tag which is what prompted this question), but I think requiring (instead of suggesting) may prevent some bad tags from being created. If a tag is worth creating, perhaps it's worth creating guidance on? That's my line of thought at the moment.

Comment: @Goose the handful times I had to create a tag, I had to make sure I will be spending time crafting the tag excerpt. I could easily use 1 hour to write a sentence. That is something most people isn't willing to spend.