# This tag is not [rational]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Not to be confused with [this sentence is false](https://youtu.be/JR4H76SCCzY?t=13). Related to [this dumpster fire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348131/the-ibm-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated), however.

[rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational)

So, we have a tag that's pulling the whole "It means *this*, except when it means *that*" mess.

> A rational is a number that can be expressed as the ratio of two integers. Rational can also refer to IBM's Rational family of products.

So, we need to disambiguate this. I'm doing #1 as part of the aforementioned <s>dumpster fire</s> burnination

1. Retag the IBM stuff to [ibm-rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-rational) ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))
2. Rename [rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational) to [rational-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational-number) for clarity ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))

Comment: This post is rational.

Comment: Machavity [[tag:ibm-rad]] may be better, it has 337 questions tagged vs [[tag:ibm-rational]] having only 32.  From the descriptions they both seem to be describing the same thing.  If someone with more IBM Rational experience can provide some input that would be great.

Comment: @JoshMc I suspect (having cleaned those out) that we'll need a separate Meta for what to do with [tag:ibm-rational], [tag:ibm-rad] and [tag:ibm-jazz] (Rational's name prior to IBM buying Jazz). They may all need to be synonymed but not sure. For now, these [rational] Qs are under the [ibm-rational] tag

Comment: There is also a tag specific to the IBM i platform (Used to be AS/400 then iSeries), [[tag:rational-developer-for-i]], this is discussed on meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345415/what-is-this-rational-developer-for-i-tag).

Comment: I'd prefer the singular ([rational-number]) over the plural

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that multi-use tags are a big problem. As a relatively new user, I remember asking my first question and tagging it - if I saw a tag which was roughly relevant, I used it. If there was a tag which was a little ambiguous, I avoided it. However not all users are the same and some users would use it anyway, as (other than being berated in the comments for using a tag incorrectly) there is no real downside to tagging like this; you end up with the potential for finding completely irrelevant posts in a tag that you follow - which is enough of a problem when people do things like tagging [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) code as [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) questions as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and doesn't need encouraging through multi-use tags.

Tags with two similar uses are one thing (see CSS tag applying to HTML, XML, etc) but tags with two completely unrelated uses are entirely unhelpful IMO.